# React Form Through Json Return

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

[image]I am making an ecommerce website in ASP.NET MVC but my V(View) is in React.js.
My database is as follows
Product(PId[P.K],PName,PDescription,PImage,PPrice,PCategoryId[F.K])
Category(CId[P.K],CName,CDescription)
My StoreManager Controller Create Class is as follows

```
    //StoreManager/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string myData, Product product)
    {
        var details = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(myData);

        string PName = (string)details["PName"];
        string PDescription = (string)details["PDescription"];
        string PImage = (string)details["PImage"];   // yeah ek masla hai hai..... ka image choose kaisa karae
        double PPrice = Convert.ToDouble((string)details["PPrice"]);
        int PCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32((string)details["PCategoryId"]); // 2nd problem we need category name not category id

        Product p = new Product() { PName = PName, PDescription = PDescription, PImage = PImage, PCategoryId = PCategoryId };
        db.Products.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

I have Issue with two things.
1. My PImage is of type string. And I have to change it to Choose File beacuse image will be choosen from files.
2. In my Form i don't want to show Category ID I want to show Category Name in a droplist
How can i achive these two targets
My view code for Create is

```
    @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Create";  
     }


     <div id="app" class="container">

     </div>

     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/babel">



     class InputValues extends React.Component
     {
        constructor(props)
        {
           super(props);
           this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
           this.ontextchange = this.ontextchange.bind(this);
           this.state = 
           {
              PName:'',
              PDescription :'',
              PImage : '',
              PPrice : '',
              PCategoryId : ''
           }
        }

        ontextchange(e)
    {
           if (e.target.id == 'PName')
           {
              this.setState({PName:e.target.value})
           }
           else if (e.target.id == 'PDescription')
           {
              this.setState({PDescription:e.target.value})
           }
           else if (e.target.id == 'PImage')
           {
              this.setState({PImage:e.target.value})
           }
           else if (e.target.id == 'PPrice')
           {
              this.setState({PPrice:e.target.value})
           }
           else (e.target.id == 'PCategoryId')
           {
              this.setState({PCategoryId:e.target.value})
           }
         }

         handleSubmit(e)
         {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = 
            {
               'PName' : this.state.PName,
               'PDescription' : this.PDescription,
               'PImage' : this.state.PImage,
               'PPrice' : this.state.PPrice,
               'PCategoryId' : this.state.PCategoryId,
             }
             //console.log(data);
             $.ajax(
             {
                type: "POST",
                url: this.props.url,
                data: { myData: JSON.stringify(data)},
                success: function (msg)
                {
                   alert("Product Added Successfully !!!!! :)");
                }
              });
            }

            render()
            {
            return(
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="PName"> Name </label><br />
              <input id="PName" onChange={this.ontextchange} type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Name" ref={this.PName} />
              <br /><br />

              <label htmlFor="PDescription"> Description </label><br />
              <input id="PDescription" onChange={this.ontextchange} type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Description" ref={this.PDescription} />
              <br /><br />

              <label htmlFor="PImage"> Image </label><br />
              <input id="PImage" onChange={this.ontextchange} type="text" placeholder=" Enter Product Image" ref={this.PImage} />
              <br /><br />

              <label htmlFor="PPrice"> Price </label><br />
              <input id="PPrice" onChange={this.ontextchange} type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Price" ref={this.PPrice} />
              <br /><br />

              <label htmlFor="PCategoryId"> Category </label><br />
              <input id="PCategoryId" onChange={this.ontextchange} type="text" placeholder="Enter PCategoryId" ref={this.PCategoryId} />
              <br /><br />

              <p>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </p>
              </form>
              </div>
              );
              }
            }
             ReactDOM.render
            (
            <InputValues url="/StoreManager/Create" />, document.getElementById("app")
            );


           </script>
```

Comment: My PImage is of type string. And I have to change it to Choose File. what do you meant by this?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV we usually add images through browse button. That when we click that browse button we can select picture from our files and than our picture (image) will be saved.

Comment: ok , but how you are going to save the image ?? byte[] ??

Comment: problem one -> you can use byte[] for getting the image and you can save it where ever you want. problem two-> you are not passing Category name from client side. so please pass category id also in the ajax post and then you can get your category name in controller.